# Get notification on change to public API response

Tags: api, jmeter, postman, soapui, httpresponse

I want to get a notification when there is a response change of a public API.

My requirement is to monitor API thorough the day and triggers notifications instantly when it is detecting.

Can I do this using API testing tools such as Postman, Soap UI or JMeter? Are there any open-source tools that fulfil my requirement?

P.S : I want to get a notification when there is a response change. Because endpoint breaks in rare cases. I think API monitoring tools detect when there is a failure in endpoint it is not detecting response changes.

Answer (score 3):

Any tool which is capable of sending a HTTP request like [curl](https://curl.se/) will do the trick for you.

Any API testing tool comes with the possibility to check the response:

1. [SoapUI - Getting started with Assertions](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions/)
2. [Postman - Making assertions on the HTTP response - Testing response body](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/test-examples/#testing-response-body)
3. [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)

With regards to "triggers notifications" - it mainly depends on what type of "notification" you need to "trigger", all the tools can be configured to execute non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) suitable for post-processing/scripting

Answer (score 2):

Create a monitor with postman,

[image]

This regularly run collection against the poublic api as per the schedule and sends you run result.

Answer (score 2):

In JMeter you can add assertion to your HTTP request which check response and fail your test in case of mismatch

You can execute JMeter test in Jenkins periodically and send notification on error

JMeter has more options and you can write code in [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

> JSR223 Sampler allows JSR223 script code to be used to perform a sample or some computation

Or/and use [SMTP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler)

> SMTP Sampler can send mail messages using SMTP/SMTPS protocol.